# I want to set a specefic expiring time for jwt refresh token

Tags: laravel, jwt, tymon-jwt

I want to set expiring time in my Tymon jwt token, but when i change the value in config file it appears that nothing changes in my database, i still have refresh tokens recorded with 2 week expiring time

I changed the value in `config/jwt.php` but nothing changed
here is the part i modified :

```php
'refresh_ttl' => env('JWT_REFRESH_TTL', 60),
```

Comment: Execute `php artisan config:clear` which will clear old configuration cached files.

Comment: "I changed the value in `config/jwt.php`", one thing, you are changing the default value or the `JWT_REFRESH_TTL` on the .env?